# apache server not responding due to HTTP CONNECT requests how to block them?

Tags: ubuntu, security, apache-2.4

Apache server is getting this kind of traffic. Due to that server is not responding. Please suggest how can we handle this issue.

```
78.135.85.252 - - [07/May/2023:16:08:33 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 492 "-" "-"
3.88.173.121 - - [07/May/2023:16:08:34 +0000] "CONNECT 92.53.96.128:443 HTTP/1.1" 200 148 "-" "-"
3.88.173.121 - - [07/May/2023:16:08:34 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 400 492 "-" "-"
78.135.85.252 - - [07/May/2023:16:08:36 +0000] "CONNECT m.113kp.com:443 HTTP/1.1" 200 204 "-" "-"
78.135.85.252 - - [07/May/2023:16:08:36 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 492 "-" "-"
54.209.41.100 - - [07/May/2023:16:08:36 +0000] "CONNECT 185.215.4.15:443 HTTP/1.1" 200 148 "-" "-"
54.209.41.100 - - [07/May/2023:16:08:37 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 400 492 "-" "-"
66.36.234.118 - - [07/May/2023:16:08:41 +0000] "CONNECT httpbin.org:443 HTTP/1.1" 200 167 "-" "-"
3.88.173.121 - - [07/May/2023:16:08:41 +0000] "CONNECT 92.53.96.128:443 HTTP/1.1" 200 148 "-" "-"
3.88.173.121 - - [07/May/2023:16:08:42 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 400 492 "-" "-"
163.172.40.251 - - [07/May/2023:16:08:46 +0000] "GET http://example.com/ HTTP/1.1" 200 148 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
78.135.85.252 - - [07/May/2023:16:09:02 +0000] "CONNECT m.113kp.com:443 HTTP/1.1" 200 204 "-" "-"
78.135.85.252 - - [07/May/2023:16:09:02 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 492 "-" "-"
13.86.22.96 - - [07/May/2023:16:09:06 +0000] "CONNECT api.ipify.org:443 HTTP/1.1" 200 148 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
13.86.22.96 - - [07/May/2023:16:09:06 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x01\x12\x01" 400 492 "-" "-"
78.135.85.252 - - [07/May/2023:16:09:23 +0000] "CONNECT m.113kp.com:443 HTTP/1.1" 200 204 "-" "-"
78.135.85.252 - - [07/May/2023:16:09:23 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 492 "-" "-"
5.255.110.95 - - [07/May/2023:16:09:32 +0000] "GET http://azenv.net/ HTTP/1.1" 200 148 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
91.151.89.197 - - [07/May/2023:16:09:35 +0000] "CONNECT m.113kp.com:443 HTTP/1.1" 200 204 "-" "-"
91.151.89.197 - - [07/May/2023:16:09:35 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 492 "-" "-"
54.209.41.100 - - [07/May/2023:16:09:41 +0000] "CONNECT 185.215.4.15:443 HTTP/1.1" 200 148 "-" "-"
54.209.41.100 - - [07/May/2023:16:09:41 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 400 492 "-" "-"
185.225.113.83 - - [07/May/2023:16:09:47 +0000] "CONNECT api.ipify.org:443 HTTP/1.1" 200 148 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0"
185.225.113.83 - - [07/May/2023:16:09:47 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 400 492 "-" "-"
54.209.41.100 - - [07/May/2023:16:09:59 +0000] "CONNECT 185.215.4.15:443 HTTP/1.1" 200 148 "-" "-"
54.209.41.100 - - [07/May/2023:16:10:01 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 400 492 "-" "-"
67.205.154.166 - - [07/May/2023:16:10:04 +0000] "CONNECT ext2-sea1.steamserver.net:27019 HTTP/1.1" 200 148 "-" "Valve/Steam HTTP Client 1.0"
67.205.154.166 - - [07/May/2023:16:10:04 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x01\xa0\x01" 400 492 "-" "-"
5.255.110.95 - - [07/May/2023:16:10:17 +0000] "GET http://azenv.net/ HTTP/1.1" 200 148 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
45.12.112.162 - - [07/May/2023:16:10:18 +0000] "GET http://azenv.net/ HTTP/1.1" 200 167 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
3.88.173.121 - - [07/May/2023:16:10:20 +0000] "CONNECT 92.53.96.128:443 HTTP/1.1" 200 148 "-" "-"
3.88.173.121 - - [07/May/2023:16:10:21 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 400 492 "-" "-"
162.158.62.204 - - [07/May/2023:16:10:24 +0000] "GET /privacypolicy.html HTTP/1.1" 404 501 "-" "PlayStore-Google"
54.209.41.100 - - [07/May/2023:16:10:25 +0000] "CONNECT 185.215.4.15:443 HTTP/1.1" 200 148 "-" "-"
54.209.41.100 - - [07/May/2023:16:10:26 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 400 492 "-" "-"
3.88.173.121 - - [07/May/2023:16:10:36 +0000] "CONNECT 92.53.96.128:443 HTTP/1.1" 200 148 "-" "-"
78.135.85.252 - - [07/May/2023:16:10:39 +0000] "CONNECT m.113kp.com:443 HTTP/1.1" 200 204 "-" "-"
78.135.85.252 - - [07/May/2023:16:10:40 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 492 "-" "-"
54.209.41.100 - - [07/May/2023:16:10:41 +0000] "CONNECT 185.215.4.15:443 HTTP/1.1" 200 148 "-" "-"
3.88.173.121 - - [07/May/2023:16:10:41 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 400 492 "-" "-"
54.209.41.100 - - [07/May/2023:16:10:44 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 400 492 "-" "-"
3.88.173.121 - - [07/May/2023:16:10:55 +0000] "CONNECT 92.53.96.128:443 HTTP/1.1" 200 148 "-" "-"
3.88.173.121 - - [07/May/2023:16:10:55 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 400 492 "-" "-"
3.88.173.121 - - [07/May/2023:16:10:58 +0000] "CONNECT 92.53.96.128:443 HTTP/1.1" 200 148 "-" "-"
3.88.173.121 - - [07/May/2023:16:10:58 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 400 492 "-" "-"
3.88.173.121 - - [07/May/2023:16:10:59 +0000] "CONNECT 92.53.96.128:443 HTTP/1.1" 200 148 "-" "-"
54.209.41.100 - - [07/May/2023:16:11:00 +0000] "CONNECT 185.215.4.15:443 HTTP/1.1" 200 148 "-" "-"
54.209.41.100 - - [07/May/2023:16:11:01 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 400 492 "-" "-"
70.34.201.180 - - [07/May/2023:16:11:01 +0000] "CONNECT ip-api.com:80 HTTP/1.1" 200 148 "-" "Python/3.11 python-socks/2.2.0"
70.34.201.180 - - [07/May/2023:16:11:02 +0000] "GET /json/?fields=8217 HTTP/1.1" 404 433 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:112.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/112.0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a webserver logs (many) successful `CONNECT` requests (as evidenced by the `200` HTTP success codes) the web server is being used as a ***forward  proxy***.

When those requests do not originate exclusively from your own network your forward proxy is not (properly) secured with access restrictions. That is typically called an *"open proxy"*.

Random clients on the internet can use an open proxy and your server to hide their own IP-address.

That *can* be intentional, by design and philosophy, for example to provide online anonymity and allow people to circumvent online censorship.

A big problem is that many open proxies (only) get used for abuse and nefarious purposes.

---

Typically an **open proxy is the result of a misconfiguration** though.

Fairly typical cause is novice administrators using the incorrect [`ProxyRequests`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyrequests) directive rather than (only) a ProxyPass to configure Apache httpd as a reverse proxy.

- Apache httpd should always be configured with `ProxyRequests Off`
- A Reverse Proxy gets configured with a `ProxyPass` directive and does NOT need `ProxyRequests on`
- When you do need a forward proxy, use one of the many dedicated proxy servers rather than your web server IMHO.
- If you still want to use Apache httpd as forward proxy, [**secure your configuration**](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#access) and limit access to only authorised clients.

Answer (score 0):

Your site is used as proxy via CONNECT method.

One possible way to mitigate is to disable CONNECT method as it is described [here](https://www.techstacks.com/howto/disable-http-methods-in-apache.html).

> `LoadModule  rewrite_module  path/to/apache/modules/mod_rewrite.so`
>
> To enable the rewrite engine, add the following:
>
> `RewriteEngine On`
>
> Please note that by default, rewrite configurations are not inherited
> across virtual servers. Add RewriteEngine On to each virtual host. The
> Disable HTTP Methods Rewrite Rule
>
> Since we are looking to disable specific http methods in this HOWTO,
> our rewrite rule has two components: a condition and the rule to be
> applied when that condition is met. In this HOWTO, my example rule
> will disable both HTTP TRACE and HTTP TRACK requests, (even though
> TRACK isn't supported by Apache) as well as HTTP OPTIONS requests,
> (even though disabling HTTP OPTIONS isn't necessarily a best
> practice). Below is the rule:
>
> `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK|OPTIONS)`   
> `RewriteRule .* - [F]`

Comment: I would rather attempt to figure out *why* Apache is running as an open proxy in the first place: That's not the default configuration. Blocking via mod_rewrite is a *poor* practice.

Comment: @vidarlo, true about open proxy. About disable CONNECT - sure, there are probably other methods, this is the first I find.